# Python Child Class with multiple init methods?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, oop, subclass

I have an application I'm building in Python2.7 that works as-is, but doesn't feel clean, nor is it very explicit in what's happening, so if I walk away from the code for a while I have a hard time remembering how it's actually working under the hood, which is obviously not good. I've refactored the code and it seems more explicit, but not really any cleaner.

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to initialize these classes in two different ways - 1) from a user-generated instantiation (in the event of adding a new object from scratch during program execution), or 2) from importing the history of an object (from a previous program execution) from JSON. Here's my latest way of going about this:

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, dev_type, preset_prefix, default_preset,
                 from_json=False, json_path=None, **device_attrs):

    if not from_json:  # otherwise set in child class __init__
        self.name = device_attrs['name']
        self.sn = device_attrs['sn']
        self.mfg = device_attrs['mfg']
        self.tech = device_attrs['tech']
        self.model = device_attrs['model']
        self.sw_ver = device_attrs['sw_ver']
        self.hours = 0
    else:
        self.hours = device_attrs['hours']

    self.type = dev_type
    self.json = json_path
    self.preset_prefix = preset_prefix
    self.preset = default_preset

class Monitor(Device):
    def __init__(self, name, sn, mfg, tech, model, sw_ver, from_json=False,
                 json_path=None, **monitor_dict):
        if from_json:
            self.__dict__ = monitor_dict
        device_properties = {'name': name, 'sn': sn, 'mfg': mfg, 'tech': tech,
                             'model': model, 'sw_ver': sw_ver}
        monitor_dict.update(device_properties)
        super(Monitor, self).__init__('monitor', 'user', 1, from_json,
                                      json_path, **monitor_dict)
        if cals:
            self._init_cal_from_json(monitor_dict['cals'])
```

Now I can initialize from a previously saved JSON (generated from this object so I can be sure the key/value pairs are correct):

```
my_monitor = Monitor(from_json=True, json_path=device_json_file, **device_json_dict))
```

Or as a new object from scratch:

```
my_monitor = Monitor('monitor01', '12345', 'HP', 'LCD',
                     'HP-27', 'v1.0')
```

This seems a little bit messy, but still better than my original version which didn't have any positional arguments for the child **init** (making it hard to know what data MUST be passed in), it just took **monitor_dict hoping it contained the right key/value pairs. However this method of taking those arguments and merging them into a dict seems strange, but I've refactored this multiple times and this seems to be the cleanest way of going about it.

Is this the best way to handle initializing an object in multiple ways or can I somehow create two separate **init** functions, one for loading from JSON, and one for new creation of brand new objects?

Comment: Having additional constructor methods (using the `@classmethod` decorator), as shown in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45292417/2437514), is a pretty typical Python idiom. There are a number of examples in the standard library (one that comes to mind is the `dict.fromkeys()` method). Use `__init__` for the most-used- or most expected- constructor, and create other constructors as  needed. So I suggest adding a `from_json` method.

Comment: Hi @ice, I've checked the edited question, if you may a suggestion, you should probably ask another question, with the new problems, I mean, my answer solve only your main and original question (for python 3, my mistake), if you ask a new question, with the new problems (and also a link to this question) you will success, i can guarantee it happend before to someone else i help. If you ask a new question let me know please, with all the details :), I hope I could help more

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create new constructors as class methods, something like this, you could create more if you need, or adjust it if necesary:

```
class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, dev_type, preset_prefix, default_preset, json_path=None, **device_attrs):


      self.name = device_attrs['name']
      self.sn = device_attrs['sn']
      self.mfg = device_attrs['mfg']
      self.tech = device_attrs['tech']
      self.model = device_attrs['model']
      self.sw_ver = device_attrs['sw_ver']
      self.hours = 0

      self.type = dev_type
      self.json = json_path
      self.preset_prefix = preset_prefix
      self.preset = default_preset

class Monitor(Device):


    @classmethod
    def new_from_json(self, name, sn, mfg, tech, model, sw_ver, json_path=None, **monitor_dict):
        self.__dict__ = monitor_dict
        device_properties = {'name': name, 'sn': sn, 'mfg': mfg, 'tech': tech,
                             'model': model, 'sw_ver': sw_ver}
        monitor_dict.update(device_properties)
        super(Monitor, self).__init__('monitor', 'user', 1,
                                      json_path, **monitor_dict)
```

As an example:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self,some):
        self.some = some


class Object(Parent):

    @classmethod
    def new_from_dict(self,some):
        Parent.__init__(self,some)
        self.adress = {"Me": 123}
        return self
```

then:

```
obj = Object.new_from_dict("ME")
obj.adress

{"Me": 123}

obj.some

"ME"
```

Comment: Thank you, I've read about classmethods and factories before but didn't really put two and two together on how to apply it here. A little extra reading after your answer here got me what I think is a clean, logical solution. I've updated my question to include a revised version.

Comment: I actually was trying something closer to what you did here for a different type  of class I have where my revised code doesn't really apply or work. The problem I'm having that I can't understand - in the code you provided, what is self referring to in new_from_json()? At that point in the code, nothing has been initialized so self is not referring to any particular object, and the self.__dict__ would not actaully work? Am I missing something?

Comment: @iceblueorbitz I will add an example for you at the end, so maybe you could see it better

Comment: Doing exactly this is still causing the same problem: TypeError: unbound method `__init__() must be called with Parent instance as first argument (got type instance instead)`.  When using the classmethod decorator, PyCharm is suggesting to use cls instead of self, and then initializing with cls(some), but this will call the subclass "Object" __init__, which in this case doesn't exist.

Comment: @iceblueorbitz try change the class for super, I did it in python 3.6 and worked fine as it is. that's error is odd..

Comment: I'm in Python 2.7, and no matter what I do, I cannot make your code work.  Since this is a classmethod of the child class, Python is expecting the first argument to be 'cls' instead of 'self', since there is no self instance to refer to yet.

Comment: @iceblueorbitz aaah I get why now, you are in python 2.7, so the sintaxis is a little different, I will edit this soon

Comment: As to avoid convoluting the original question - I'm just leaving the original question and code. I still don't think your answer is valid, however, as there is no object to pass into the Parent `__init__` instance method when you call it. I asked this in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429815/child-class-constructor-using-super-getting-unbound-method-init/45430293#45430293) and based on that response and my research, your answer is still not valid from what I see unless you first create an instance with `__new__`.