# Child Class constructor using super() - getting unbound method __init__()

Tags: python-2.7, constructor, superclass, class-method

I'm trying to create classmethod constructors for a child class, but I cannot initialize the instance properly.

I have read many blogs and answers on this site and even tried exactly what some other people have posted, still to no avail. Hopefully I'm missing something really simple. Basic example of what I'm trying:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def make_new(cls):
        super(B, cls).__init__('bar')

foobar = B.make_new()
```

I keep getting unbound method error:

```
TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with B instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: I'm glad you took my advice of asking a new question after get stuck in a new point. I knew you'd achieve it ;), Is a plus one for the question, sorry if I couldn't answer in time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__init__` method is a regular instance method, not a class method. It needs the instance it is going to initialize to already have been created when it is called. Your current code is failing in exactly the same way that `A.__init__("foo")` would fail (it's not the fault of `super`).

I suspect you wanted to be calling `__new__` rather than `__init__`. The `__new__` method is the actual "constructor" method that is responsible for creating the instance (usually by delegating the actual creation step to `object.__new__`). You don't need to use `super` either, since you've not overridden the `__new__` method that you inherited (from `object`, since `A` doesn't override it either).

But you don't actually need to do that either. You can just call the `cls` argument your `classmethod` been passed. Calling a class is the normal way to construct instances:

```
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def make_new(cls):
        return cls("bar")  # note that you also need to `return` the instance you create!
```

If the purpose of the class method is to avoid running `B.__init__`, you might want something like:

```
class B(A):
    @classmethod
    def make_new(cls):
        self = cls.__new__(cls)
        super(B, self).__init__('bar')
        return self
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense and was what I figured the issue was, but in my particular case (actual code I'm working on), I did override the base class init in class B hence the super. I'm trying to use this classmethod as an alternate constructor that is still a B instance but doesn't follow B's init process. Specifically it's for loading previous instance state that was saved as JSON and reconstructing it back into it's object form. This follows a different process then creating a new object from scratch.

Comment: Ah, then you probably want to do `self = cls.__new__()` followed by `super(B, self).__init__()` (with whatever arguments are necessary). If `B` has it's own `__new__` method that you want to bypass, you'd want to call `super(B, cls).__new__(cls)` instead of just `cls.__new__`, but that shouldn't be necessary if you're only needing to bypass an overridden `__init__` method.

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes perfect sense, and seems to be important missing information from many other posts and topics I've seen. I understand that '__new__' is often frowned upon, but works great in my case of needing separate logic for re-loading history from a JSON dict and reconstructing the object.

Comment: @iceblueorbitz I'm really happy you find your answer finally, sorry I was to late in answer, but I tried to do something like that, but I didn't know all that cool stuff from python 2.7. Blccngth your answer is grate! It's a plus hundred if I could :)